Script Continuously Requests face_recognition_models Installation Despite Being Installed
I'm encountering an issue with a Python script that utilizes the face_recognition library. Despite having successfully installed the face_recognition_models package, the script repeatedly prompts me to install it when I attempt to execute the script. Here's the command and output I receive:

the code :
import os
import face_recognition
import face_recognition_models
import cv2


image_path = "tes.png"

# Check if the image file exists
if not os.path.isfile(image_path):
    print("Image file does not exist:", image_path)
    exit()

# Get a reference to webcam #0 (the default one)
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Load your image and learn how to recognize it.
image = face_recognition.load_image_file(image_path)
face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(image)[0]

# Create arrays of known face encodings and their names
known_face_encodings = [
    face_encoding,
]
known_face_names = [
        "Walid"
]

while True:
        # Grab a single frame of video
        ret, frame = video_capture.read()

        # Convert the image from BGR color (which OpenCV uses) to RGB color (which face_recognition uses)
        rgb_frame = frame[:, :, ::-1]

        # Find all the faces in the current frame of video
        face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_frame)
        face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_frame, face_locations)

        # Loop through each face in this frame of video
        for (top, right, bottom, left), face_encoding in zip(face_locations, face_encodings):
            # See if the face is a match for the known face(s)
            matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)

            name = "Unknown"

            if True in matches:
                first_match_index = matches.index(True)
                name = known_face_names[first_match_index]

            # Draw a box around the face
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)

            # Draw a label with a name below the face
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
            cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)

        # Display the resulting image
        cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

        # Hit 'q' on the keyboard to quit!
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

# Release handle to the webcam
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


I attempted to execute a Python script utilizing the face_recognition library. Despite successfully installing the face_recognition_models package, the script continuously prompted me to install it when executed. I expected the script to recognize the installed package and execute without errors, but it continued to request installation of face_recognition_models.

Why don't you try just 'pip install face_recognition' w/o git and clone? Normally it also installs face_recognition_models by itself too.  And you don't need to import face_recognition_models manually at your script as well.
